# How to fix bug in code for printing two-dimensional table in COBOL program?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, cobol

I am creating a program that processes real estate data in COBOL on unix. The program prints both a one dimensional table and a two dimensional table (the rows of the two dimensional table will represent the number of bedrooms and the columns will represent the number of bathrooms). I want to know why I can't change this line of code:

```
 01 Accum-table2.
      02 Bed-Accum2 occurs 6 pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
         02 Bath-Accum2 occurs 3 
           pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
```

TO this line of code:

```
       01 Accum-table2.
         02 Bed-Accum2 occurs 6 pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
              03 Bath-Accum2 occurs 3 
                  pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
```

^^this causes a hierarchy error although i think it is the source of my two dimensional table printing wrong.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
                                   Baths  
                 1          2          3          4          5

     Bedrms
            1

            2

            3

                    ..etc..
```

And now for the full code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. prog5.
    Author. Raoul Duke.      


    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
    Input-output Section.
    File-Control.
            select input-file assign to 
              "/home1/c/a/acsi203/realestate.dat".
            select input-file2 assign to
              "/home1/c/a/acsi203/city.dat".
            select output-file assign to "prog5out.dat"
               organization is line sequential. 
            select error-file assign to "error5out.dat"
               organization is line sequential.        

    DATA    DIVISION.
    File    Section.
    FD      Input-File.
    01      INPUT-REC.
            02 PropertyAddress  pic x(27).
            02 City             pic a(15).
            02 Zip              pic 9(5).
            02 State            pic a(2).
              88 Valid-State    value "CA".
            02 Bedrooms         pic 9.
            02 Bathrooms        pic 9.
            02 SqFt             pic 9(4).
            02 PropertyType     pic x(8).
              88 Valid-Prop     value "Resident"
                  "Condo" "Multi-Fa".
            02 SaleDayofWeek    pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleMonth        pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleDay          pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleHour         pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleMinute       pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleSecond       pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 TimeZone         pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleYear         pic 9(4).
            02 SalePrice        pic 9(6).
            02 PropertyLatitude pic 99v999999.
            02 PropertyLongitude pic 99v9(7).
            02 filler pic x. 
    FD      Input-File2.
    01      INPUT-REC2.
            02 City2            pic a(15).
            02 Tax-Rate1        pic V999.
            02 Filler           pic x.

    FD  OUTPUT-FILE
        linage is 58 lines
        with footing at 55
        lines at top 5
        lines at bottom 5.
    01  OUTPUT-REC              pic x(132).

    FD  ERROR-FILE.
    01  Error-rec               pic x(132).

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 REPORT-HEADER.

            02 Filler           pic x(49) value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(70) value 
              "Sacramento Area Real Estate Transactions".
            02 Filler           pic x(61) value spaces.
    01 CURRENT-DATE.
            02 CurrentYear-out      pic 9(4).
            02 CurrentMonth-out     pic 99.
            02 CurrentDay-out       pic 99.
    01 RECORDS-PROCESSED.
            02 Filler           pic x(28) value 
                    "Number Of Records Processed:".
            02 num-recs         pic 9(3)   value 0.
            02 Filler           pic x(15) value spaces.
    01 AVERAGE-PROCESSED.
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value
                    "Average: ".
            02 num-nonzero      pic 9(4) value 0.
            02 Filler           pic x(42) value spaces.
            02 BedroomAverage-out pic zz9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value spaces.
            02 BathroomAverage-out pic zz9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(18) value spaces.
            02 SqFtAverage-out  pic ZZZZ9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(4) value spaces.
            02 SalePriceAverage-out pic $ZZZ,ZZ9.99.


    01 The-City-Table.
            02 City-Table occurs 22 times
               indexed by City2-index
               ascending key is City2-code.
                03 City2-code     pic a(15).
                03 Tax-Rate       pic V999.
                 01 row-index pic 9.
                 01 column-index pic 9.
                 01 city-index pic 99 value 1.
    01 Accum-table.
            02 Bed-Accum occurs 6 pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
    01 Accum-table2.
            02 Bed-Accum2 occurs 6 pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
                       02 Bath-Accum2 occurs 3 
                           pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
    01 END-OF-REPORT.
            02 Filler           pic x(13) value
                    "End Of Report".

    01 table-out. 
            02 filler pic x(35) value spaces.
            02 bed-num pic 9 value zero.
            02 filler pic x(7) value spaces.
            02 accum-out pic $ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.99.
    01 table2-out.
            02 filler      pic x(35) value spaces.
            02 bed-num2    pic 9 value zero.
            02 filler      pic x(7) value spaces.
            02 accum2-out  pic $ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.99.
            02 filler      pic x(7) value spaces.
            02 Bath-Accum  pic 9 value zero.
            02 accum3-out  pic $ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.99.


    01 COLUMN-HEADER.
            02 Filler           pic x(7) value "Address".
            02 Filler           pic x(17) value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(4)  value "City".
               02 Filler           pic x(10) value spaces.
               02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "Zip".
               02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
               02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "State".
               02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
               02 Filler           pic x(4)  value "Beds".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "Baths".
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(4) value "Prop".
            02 Filler           pic x(6)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value "Price".
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value "Price/Sqft".
            02 Filler           pic x(3)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "Taxes".
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(8)  value "Tax-Rate".

    01 INFO-LINE.
            02 PropertyAddress-out      pic x(20).
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 City-out         pic a(15).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 Zip-out          pic 9(6).
            02 Filler           pic x(2) value spaces.
            02 State-out        pic a(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value spaces.
            02 Bedrooms-out         pic 9.
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value spaces.
            02 Bathrooms-out        pic 9.
            02 Filler           pic x(3) value spaces.
            02 PropertyType-out     pic x(8).
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 SalePrice-out    pic 9(6).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 PriceSqFtT-out   pic $ZzZ,ZZ9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 Taxes-out        pic $zzz,zz9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 Tax-Rate1-out    pic $zz,zz9.99.
    01 TEMP-VAR.
            02 PriceSqFtT       pic 9(5)v99 value zero.
            02 PriceSqFtAccum   pic 9(6)v99 value zero.
            02 BedroomAverage   pic 9(4)v99 value zero.
            02 BathroomAverage  pic 9(4)v99 value zero.
            02 SqFtAverage      pic 9(6)v99 value zero.
            02 SalePriceAverage pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
            02 Taxes            pic 9(7)v99 value zero.
            02 bedtotal         pic 9(4)v99 value zero.
            02 bathtotal        pic 9(4)v99 value zero.
            02 sqfttotal        pic 9(6)v99 value zero.
            02 salepricetotal   pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
            02 temp-tax         pic 9(7)v99 value zero.
            02 row-index1       pic 99 value 1.
            02 column-index1    pic 99 value 1.

    01 eof-flag2                pic x(3) value "No".
    01 eof-flag                 pic x(3) value "No".
        88 End-Reached          value "yes".
    01 invalid-flag             pic x(3) value "No".
        88 Bad-Record           value "yes".
    01 eop-flag   pic x(3) value "No".
        88 page-end             value "yes". 
    01 page-footer.
           02 Filler pic x(60) value spaces.
           02 page-num    pic 9 value 1.
    01 blank-line         pic x(132) value spaces.             

    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    0000-MAIN-LOGIC.
            Perform 1000-init.
            Perform 2000-main-loop until end-reached.
            Perform 3000-finish.
            stop run.

    1000-init.
            open input input-file input-file2
            output output-file error-file.
            write output-rec from Report-Header.
            write output-rec from Current-Date.
            ACCEPT Current-Date FROM DATE YYYYMMDD.
            write output-rec from Column-Header.
            Read input-file2 at end move "yes" to eof-flag2.
            perform 1010-Load-Table until city-index > 22.
            Read input-file at end move "yes" to eof-flag.

    1010-Load-Table.

            move input-rec2 to city-table(city-index).
            add 1 to city-index. 
            read input-file2 at end move "yes" to eof-flag2.

    1999-Page-End.
            write output-rec from page-footer after
                        advancing 3 lines.
            if not end-reached
               write output-rec from column-header 
                         after advancing page.
            add 1 to page-num.

    2000-main-loop.
            move "no" to eof-flag.
            perform 2100-Validate.
            If Bad-Record 
             perform 2999-error
            else
             perform 2200-process.
            read input-file at end move "yes" to eof-flag.

    2100-validate.
            If not Valid-State or not Valid-Prop or
             Bedrooms not numeric or Bathrooms not
             numeric or SqFT not numeric or
             SalePrice not numeric
              move "yes" to invalid-flag.

    2999-error.
            write error-rec from input-rec.            
            if not valid-state
             move "invalid state" to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            if not Valid-Prop
             move "invalid prop" to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            if Bedrooms not numeric
             move "Bedrooms were not numeric"
             to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            if Bathrooms not numeric
             move "Bathrooms were not numeric"
              to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            if SqFt not numeric
             move "not numeric" to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            if SalePrice not numeric
             move "not numeric" to error-rec
             write error-rec.
            move "No" to invalid-flag.


    2200-process.
            search all city-table
              at end display "No Match"
            when city = city2-code(City2-Index)
              compute temp-tax  = salePrice * Tax-Rate(City2-Index).
            move temp-tax to tax-rate1-out. 
            move PropertyAddress to PropertyAddress-out.
            move City to City-out.
            move Zip to Zip-out.
            move State to State-out.
            move Bedrooms to Bedrooms-out.
            move Bathrooms to Bathrooms-out.
            move PropertyType to PropertyType-out.
            move SalePrice to SalePrice-out.
  **move '12ABCDEF34GHIJKL5MNOPQR' TO The-City-Table.
  **perform 1000-init VARYING I FROM 1 by 1 until I > 3
  **STOP RUN.


            divide SalePrice by sqFt giving PriceSqFtT.
            Add SalePrice to  PriceSqFtAccum.
            Move PriceSqFtT to PriceSqFtT-out.
            add 1 to num-recs.
            If sqft = 0
              Move 0 to PricesqftT.
            if sqft not = 0 
                 add 1 to num-nonzero.
            IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" and Bedrooms >= 2

               compute Taxes = salePrice * .075.
            IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" and Bedrooms < 2 
               MULTIPLY salePrice by .065 giving Taxes.
            IF city NOT EQUAL "SACRAMENTO"
               MULTIPLY salePrice  by .06 giving Taxes.

            IF bedrooms > 0
               add saleprice to bed-accum(bedrooms).
             IF bedrooms > 0
               add saleprice to bed-accum2(bedrooms).


            move Taxes to Taxes-out.
            add Bedrooms to bedtotal.
            add Bathrooms to bathtotal.
            add SqFt to sqfttotal.
            add SalePrice to salepricetotal.
            divide Bedtotal by num-nonzero giving BedroomAverage.
            divide Bathtotal by num-nonzero giving BathroomAverage.
            divide sqfttotal by num-nonzero giving SqFtAverage.
            divide salepricetotal by num-recs giving
            SalePriceAverage.
            move BedroomAverage to BedroomAverage-out.
            move BathroomAverage to BathroomAverage-out.
            move SqFtAverage to SqFtAverage-out.
            move SalePriceAverage to SalePriceAverage-out.
            write output-rec from info-line
                       at eop perform 1999-page-end.

    3000-finish.
            write output-rec from average-processed.
            write output-rec from Records-processed.
            perform 3200-check.
            perform 3100-table varying row-index1
                  from 1 by 1 until row-index1 > 6.
            perform 3200-check.
            perform 3150-table2 varying row-index1
                  from 1 by 1 until row-index1 > 6
                  after column-index from 1 by 1 until
                  column-index > 3.
            perform 3200-check.
            write output-rec from END-OF-REPORT.
            close input-file output-file error-file.

    3100-table.
            move row-index1 to bed-num.
            move bed-accum(row-index1) to accum-out.
            write output-rec from table-out.
     3150-table2.
            move row-index1 to bed-num2.
            move column-index to Bath-accum.
            move bed-accum2(row-index1) to accum2-out.
            move Bath-Accum2(column-index1) to accum3-out.
            write output-rec from table2-out.
     3200-check.
           if not page-end
             perform 3250-blanks until page-end.
           if page-end
             perform 1999-page-end.
           move "no" to eop-flag.

     3250-blanks.
           write output-rec from blank-line
                  at eop move "yes" to eop-flag.
```

OUTPUT TABLES:

Correct one dimensional:

```
                               1       $    454,852.00
                               2       $  5,285,635.00
                               3       $ 19,120,759.00
                               4       $ 12,888,340.00
                               5       $  4,544,850.00
                               6       $  1,112,400.00




























                                                        6
```

Incorrect Two Dimensional:

```
                               1       $    454,852.00       1$          0.00
                               1       $    454,852.00       2$          0.00
                               1       $    454,852.00       3$          0.00
                               2       $  5,285,635.00       1$          0.00
                               2       $  5,285,635.00       2$          0.00
                               2       $  5,285,635.00       3$          0.00
                               3       $ 19,120,759.00       1$          0.00
                               3       $ 19,120,759.00       2$          0.00
                               3       $ 19,120,759.00       3$          0.00
                               4       $ 12,888,340.00       1$          0.00
                               4       $ 12,888,340.00       2$          0.00
                               4       $ 12,888,340.00       3$          0.00
                               5       $  4,544,850.00       1$          0.00
                               5       $  4,544,850.00       2$          0.00
                               5       $  4,544,850.00       3$          0.00
                               6       $  1,112,400.00       1$          0.00
                               6       $  1,112,400.00       2$          0.00
                               6       $  1,112,400.00       3$          0.00
```

Comment: Your required output shows five bathrooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group item *cannot* contain a PICture clause.

You have this:

```
   01 Accum-table2.
     02 Bed-Accum2 occurs 6 pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
          03 Bath-Accum2 occurs 3 
              pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
```

That will not compile.

You probably intend something like this:

```
   01 Accum-table2.
     02 Bed-Accum2 occurs 6.
          03 Bath-Accum2 occurs 3 
              pic 9(9)v99 value zero.
```

This will allow values for up to six bedrooms with up to three bathrooms. Bear in mind that a luxury six-bedroom property could easily have eight bathrooms, or more, depending on how you define a bathroom :-)

As a beginner, there are a number of things with your code you may want to reconsider:

Use of scope-delimiters: You are using a full-stop/period to delimit scope. Prior to the 1985 COBOL standard, this was the only way to delimit scope. The 1985 Standard introduced a whole range of explicit scrop-delimiters, like END-IF and END-READ, and greatly relaxed the number of full-stops/periods required in the PROCEDURE DIVISION. I'd strongly recommend the use of explicit scope delimiters in place of full-stops/periods and the abandonment of the routine use of a full-stop/period on every line.

Indentation: pay attention and be consistent with this. It is common practice when defining data to leave "gaps" in the level-numbers that you use, so that a structure can be changed without having to re-number almost everything.

88s and SET: You use 88s, giving the field they relate to a value with MOVE, and using names for those fields which are not close to the 88s themselves. The easiest way to improve this is to use SET 88-name TO TRUE, and also establish another 88 which clearly negates that, and SET that to TRUE when you want to turn a flag off.

Paragrpah-numbering: as a beginner, do it once the program is complete. Then you can move paragraphs around without having to re-number.

Reliance on existing values: be careful about using something which just happens to have the value you want from the last time the code was executed. Set everything *before* it is needed for that data, not *after* the last data was processed. It is difficult to spot that.